# JASidePanels example-2 using storyboards : crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, open-source, storyboard

I am trying to implement the JASidePanels example2 using storyboard.
https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels#example-2-storyboards

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
  [self setLeftPanel:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"leftViewController"]];
  [self setCenterPanel:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"centerViewController"]];
  [self setLeftPanel:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"rightViewController"]];
}
```

If I added above code into CenterViewController.m that was as same as MySidePanelController.m in the example2, the app was crashed like below.

[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6655378/stack1.png]

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
//  [self setLeftPanel:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"leftViewController"]];
//  [self setCenterPanel:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"centerViewController"]];
//  [self setLeftPanel:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"rightViewController"]];
}
```

If I commented out like above, the app worked like below.
[image: ttps://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6655378/stack2.png]

I'm new to iOS.
Could you tell me what is wrong?

My environment.

- XCode : Version 4.6.2
- iOS SDK : 6.1
- Simulator : iPhone 6.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are causing a stackoverflow by calling the code in `-awakeFromNib` in your center view controller as it sets another center view controller as its center panel and goes this way till the app crashes.

You need to have a subclass of `JASidePanelController` where you implement the`-awakeFromNib` and your other 3 view controllers that you set as panels.

```
#import "JASidePanelController.h"

@interface MyPanelsController : JASidePanelController

@end


#import "MyPanelsController.h"

@implementation MyPanelsController

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [self setLeftPanel:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"leftViewController"]];
    [self setCenterPanel:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"centerViewController"]];
    [self setRightPanel:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"rightViewController"]];
}

@end
```

And in your storyboard drag a `UIViewController` and set its class to `MyPanelsController` and set it as the initial view controller.

Comment: Thanks @suzu for asking the question and thanks @ Moxy for the simple illustrated answer, keep rocking guys!

Comment: @Moxy When I do this, the panels work fine. However the icon on the `leftBarButtonItem` and the `rightBarButtonItem` do not display. Any idea why?

Comment: @gotnull is the center panel a navigation controller?